# App crash only on Android 6.0 with ImageButton

Tags: android, crash

My app crashes on the Android 6.0 (emulator or a real Samsung S5) with an `InflateException`. However it works without problems on any other device with Android 7.0 to 9.0

Stacktrace:

```
02-19 08:58:28.458 4408-4408/com.audiodesignguide.www.hqp6 W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f08008c (t=7 e=140) (error -75)
02-19 08:58:28.459 4408-4408/com.audiodesignguide.www.hqp6 D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
02-19 08:58:28.483 4408-4408/com.audiodesignguide.www.hqp6 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.audiodesignguide.www.hqp6, PID: 4408
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #31: Binary XML file line #31: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageButton
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    at com.audiodesignguide.www.hqp6.HomeFragment.onCreateView(HomeFragment.java:114)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2439)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1460)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1852)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:802)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2625)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2411)
```

My `onCreateView()` code:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Log.i(TAG, "HomeFragment - onCreateView() - start");

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    Log.i(TAG, "-0-");
```

This is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:theme="@style/Spinner"
android:textSize="15dp"
android:background="@color/colorBackgroundBody" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/version"
    android:layout_width="800px"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="System configuration"
    android:textColor="@color/colorTextBody"
    android:textSize="15dp" />

<ImageButton
   android:id="@+id/reload"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@null"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="210dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:src="@drawable/reload" />
```

Comment: Add layout `fragment_home` with question .

Comment: Please add the code of XML layout  fragment_home with your question

Comment: I have add the code, these are my test:

ImageBUtton +  android:src
   - Android 7.0 run ok
   - Android 6.0 crash
android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton + app:srcCompat  
   - Android 7.0 run ok
   - Android 6.0 crash

Comment: Also tested this in code, Android 7.0 run ok and Android 6.0 no crash but no image

        final ImageButton b1 = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.power);
        b1.setImageResource(R.drawable.power);

Comment: Also this code run ok on Android 7.0 and crash on Android 6.0

final ImageButton b1 = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.power);
b1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.power);

Comment: This problem might be with drawable file. Add drawble from new->Vector asset

Comment: Could you explain better what I can test ?

Comment: i had a similar issue, did u figure anything out?

Comment: is "@drawable/reload"  shapeDrawable? if it is shapeDrawable please add it's xml here too